# How do I add custom styles to Wygwam using a hook?

Tags: wygwam, config, hook, wysiwyg, ckeditor

I want to add an extension to wygwam that allows me to add my own customized dropdown to the toolbar with different css styles. No idea where to start. I want simple styles for pull-quotes and lists. Does anyone have an example of what they have done to achieve this.